# 3 meter square area vs 3 square meter area

Tags: word-order, ambiguity, hyphenation, mathematics

> A. 3 meter square area
>
> B. 3 square meter area

I’m wondering what the easiest way is to clearly express the difference between A and B above.

In A, one side is 3 (meters). In B, one side is the square root of 3 (meters).

Also, can both A and B be expressed with all the modifiers on the left, such as with hyphens? Or would word order such as the following be required for A?

> area of 3 meters squared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. *3-meter-square area* & B. *3-square-meter area* is what you are after; the hyphens bind together all the elements they connect into a single adjectival unit of meaning.

*Area of 3 meters squared* would not take the hyphens, because that expression is constructed in such a manner that its elements are not bound together in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

> A. 3 meter long square
>
> B. 3 square meter area (fine as it is)

This would clearly differentiate between the two.

Comment: Thanks. However, what if left-side modifiers are used? The writer I'm checking for tells me he prefers left-side modifiers for the term so that further left-side modifiers, or relative clauses unambiguously modifying “square”, can be added later.

Answer (score 0):

Try *a square three meters to a side* or *a three meter by three meter square*.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that the first definition may create confusion.

- A - should be, *a 3 meters squared area* or a *3 meter by 3 meter square area* ( that is a 9 squared meters area) to avoid misunderstanding.

But, I think, example B is the best way to express the concept. [square meter vs meter square](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=square%20meters,meter%20squared,%20meter%20square&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,square%20meters;,c0;.t1;,meter%20squared;,c0;.t1;,meter%20square;,c0)

Answer (score 0):

A. 3 Meter square.

B. square root of 3 is also considered 3 meter square.